# Footer not positioning below Content Div(float layout)

Tags: html, css

### HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Header_Wrapper">
      <div id="Menu_Wrapper">
        <?php include( 'menu.php');?>
      </div>
      <div id="GuardSpace_Wrapper"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Content_Wrapper">


      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 ">
          <div id="AdminLeftMenu">


            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-8 ">
          <div id="Content">
            <?php include($page_content);?>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 ">
          <div id="AdminRightMenu">


            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id="Footer_Wrapper">
      <?php include( 'footer.php');?>
    </div>
  </div>
a
</body>
```

### CSS

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #Wrapper {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
    }
    #Header_Wrapper {
        position:relative;
        height:20%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #089de3;
        float:left;

    }
    #Menu_Wrapper {
        height:80%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #GuardSpace_Wrapper {
        height:20%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #f5f5f5;
    }
    #Content_Wrapper {
         position:relative;
        height:60%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        float:left;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 8px 31px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: -4px 8px 31px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: -4px 8px 31px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }
    #Footer_Wrapper {
         position:relative;
        bottom:0;
        height:20%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #333;
        float:left;
    }
    #AdminLeftMenu{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    }
    #AdminRightMenu{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    }
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8878jma4/1/)
When the page is of grid size less than 720px or 480 px.The footer appears to above the Content_Wrapper.The wrapper hight in grid size less than 720px is less than total height of child elements .Is there any way for the content to fit

Answer (score 1):

```
#Content_Wrapper {
        overflow:hidden;
        min-height:60%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        float:left;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 8px 31px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: -4px 8px 31px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: -4px 8px 31px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }
```

..."overflow:hidden" is the key there. "height" was changed to "min-height" just because otherwise the content would not fit anyway.

```
#Content_Wrapper {
        height:60%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y:auto;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        background: #fff;
        float:left;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 8px 31px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: -4px 8px 31px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: -4px 8px 31px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8878jma4/4/embedded/result/)

Comment: I want the content to accomodate not hide overlow

Comment: I see. I posted edited answer... hope this is what you meant :)

Comment: ok :) but since I am already here... pls describe _exactly_ what would you like to achieve and I will respond in few minutes

Comment: I want the page to be resposive .And footer to be at bottom of content div and also when content div is empty it should not climb up but stick to bottom of page and contents inside the content div should not spill out but should be under each other

Comment: That is a huge question. Depends on which browsers, resolutions, OS would you like to support. And if you want to support "everything", there is no perfect way. You can use JS to subtract heights of header and footer from height of the viewport and assign this number to the height of the "Content_Wrapper". Example of more modern way can be a page I did for fun a year ago [link](http://downlister.com). Here I used calc(), that by now has pretty good support by browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=calc). It allows you to say "element should have height 100% of the viewport minus some number"...

Comment: ...and you should definitely use [media queries](http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20media%20queries). Also if you would like to be really responsive, you should consider tools that would dynamically change your font sizes, like [Flowtype](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/). You need to remember that on mobile you will have some space taken by OS "header" and mobile browser "footer" with it's options. Those are always different. So it is important to adjust your content. Anyway, I can give you some more advice and examples, but it will be always true that there is no perfect solution :(

Comment: I have built previous pages with media queries and without height to the wrapper only width:100%; and float left; and min-height:for each grid size .I was wondering if there is any other way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Change following css:

1. For `#wrapper`, Remove `height` and set min-height: 100%
2. Change header and position height to absolute instead of being in percentage, say 50px each.
3. Remove `height` from `#Content_Wrapper` and instead set `margin-bottom:50px`

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/8878jma4/5/ 
A nice article on how to place the footer http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Comment: why set min-height 100%; and explain a little more .What I am looking for is to make the footerpositioned at bottom of page as well the page as a whole be resposive

Comment: Min-height: 100% is set so that wrapper always have atleast height equal to that of screen. This will be useful if content is less so that footer doesn't climb up. If content increases height will increase and footer will be at bottom and will be visible after scroll. To achieve this, add position:relative to wrapper and position: absolute to footer with bottom:0. I have updated the fiddle to achieve that https://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/8878jma4/7/. However i had to delete float:left styles. I guess those  aren't required as you are using bootstrap which will handle those.